# Node TCP server error ECONNRESET with netcat clients

Tags: node.js, tcp, netcat

in the example NodeJS server (at end) why does (it seems) `socket.end()` on a `netcat` connection cause a **`ECONNRESET`** server error?

Observe, a socket-object error on server with client:

```
TERMINAL 1
netcat localhost 9000
Hello.
Goodbye.

TERMINAL 2
==> A Connection connected
==> The Server is disconnecting a connection
{ [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
```

Now observe, no socket-object error on server with client:

```
TERMINAL 1
telnet localhost 9000
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Hello.
Goodbye.
Connection closed by foreign host.

TERMINAL 2
==> A Connection connected
==> The Server is disconnecting a connection
==> A Connection disconnected
```

I'm looking for an answer that will fix the error, or failing that, very clearly explain why this must happen.

Many thanks,
Jason

```
import TCP from "net"
import Promise from "Bluebird"

const log = console.log



const server = TCP.createServer((conn) => {

  conn.setEncoding('utf8')

  log("==> A Connection connected")

  conn.write("Hello.\n", async function () {
    await Promise.delay(3000)
    if (!conn.destroyed) {
      log("==> The Server is disconnecting a connection")
      conn.end("Goodbye.\n")
    }
  })

  conn.on("error", log)

  conn.on("end", () => {
    log("==> A Connection disconnected")
  })

  conn.on("data", (message) => {
    log("==> A Connection says:\n%s", message)
  })
})



const port = 9000

server.listen(port, () => {
  log(`==> The Server is listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your link. If you want to get answers - include your code here

Comment: @baao Ok I've copied over the code, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this has something to do with how some versions (not all) of `netcat` handle the closing of TCP connections.

The *exact* cause goes beyond my knowledge of TCP, so I can't help you with that (all I can say is that `ECONNRESET` means that Node tried to read from a connection that was reset/closed already by `netcat`).

A solution that works for me is to call [`destroy()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_destroy_exception) on the socket once the last message was sent:

```
conn.end("Goodbye.\n")
conn.destroy()
```

I guess it presents Node from performing any more reads on the socket, which could cause the error.

Comment: I'll wait to accept a more detailed answer but this is a helpful start, so thank-you!